# Optimize spatial join between polygons that intersect other polygons using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join

I would like to select polygons that intersect another polygon layer.

So far, I worked with GeoPandas.

```
import geopandas as gpd

polygon_layer = gpd.read_file(r'file.shp') 
other_polygon = gpd.read_file('file2.shp')

subset = gpd.sjoin(polygon_layer, other_polygon, how='inner', predicate='touches')
```

However, I am not sure the spatial join is right and moreover, the spatial join takes very long time.

Comment: Intersection and touching are partially different phenomena in GIS realm.

Comment: what makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for the question. I am pretty new to work with Geopandas, and I am doing trying and error here. Is it the predicative wrong in the join?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz the first polygon layer represents a building and the second one represents the sea. Should I called it an intersection or a touching?

Comment: Are the buildings on  the sea or near the sea?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz some of the buildings are near the sea and some are not

Comment: Could you share a screenshot showing your data?

Comment: How large are the data sets, number of rows in each?

Comment: @BERA the sea is 200 k and the buildings 5 k. I am testing now the following code `gpd.sjoin(subset_test, df_sea_test, how='inner', predicate='touches')` with a smaller sample just to check whether it makes sense.